Consulta MYSQL UPDATE
tengo 2 tablas que estan relacionada id de la tabla personal y id_personal de la tabla vacaciones
tabla personal



id
grado
nombre




1
primero
Angel


2
segundo
maria



tabla Vacaciones



id
id_personal
FechaInicio (VARCHAR)
FechaFin (VARCHAR)




1
1
10 septiembre 2024
30 septiembre 2024


2
1
08 enero 2024
28 enero 2024


3
2
18 enero 2024
08 febrero 2024


4
2
18 enero 2024
08 febrero 2024



quisiera actualizar las primeras 2 fechas (fechaInicio y fechaFin) del id_personal 1 del id 1 y que solo me actualize el primer fechaInicio con el primer fechaFin porque ese seria su primer periodo de vacaciones y asi con la segunda fecha (fechaInicio y fechaFin) igual del id_personal 1 e id = 2
usando algo asi como esto, que lo ocupe para determinar el primer periodo y segundo de vacaciones
MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 1 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaInicio) END) 
    AS fechaInicio1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 1 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaFin) END) 
    AS fechaFin1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 2 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaInicio) END) 
    AS fechaInicio2,
     MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 2 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaFin) END) 
    AS fechaFin2

tengo una consulta donde en mi modal veo al usuario con sus respectivos datos y sus fechas
SELECT 
    personal.id AS personal_id,
    personal.grado,
    personal.nombre,
    MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 1 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaInicio) END) 
    AS fechaInicio1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 1 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaFin) END) 
    AS fechaFin1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 2 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaInicio) END) 
    AS fechaInicio2,
     MAX(CASE WHEN vacaciones.vacacion_num = 2 THEN CONCAT(vacaciones.fechaFin) END) 
    AS fechaFin2
FROM 
    personal
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        *,
        @row_number := IF(@prev_empleado_id = id_personal, @row_number + 1, 1) AS vacacion_num,
        @prev_empleado_id := id_personal
    FROM 
        vacaciones
    JOIN (
        SELECT @row_number := 0, @prev_empleado_id := 0
    ) AS vars
    ORDER BY 
        id_personal, fechaInicio
) AS vacaciones ON personal.id = vacaciones.id_personal
WHERE 
    personal.id = '$vacaciones_id'
GROUP BY 
    personal.id, personal.nombre



Hola. La pregunta no se entiende. Por favor, aclara lo que quisiste decir con esto: quisiera actualizar las 4 fechas (fechaInicio y fechaFin) del id_personal 1 y que solo me actualize el primer fechaInicio con el primer fechaFin porque ese seria su primer periodo de vacaciones y asi con la segunda fecha. ¿Cómo se determina que ese es el primer período de vacaciones, que sería, supongo, el criterio para el UPDATE? ¿Qué nuevo valor deben tener las fechas? Considera agregar la consulta UPDATE que estás intentando y qué error tiene. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Si por ejemplo es una consulta que depende de una fecha en sí misma, entonces podrías resolverlo mediante un evento. Pero falta contexto en la pregunta, y eso dificulta que podamos ayudarte con mayor propiedad. Mira por ejemplo esta respuesta donde dependiendo de una fecha se eleminan o actualizan registros.

Ya actualizo mi pregunta, ya que tampoco se como se determinaria que ese es el primer período de vacaciones

Hola, en base a que datos deseas hacer el update? Como deseas hacer ese update y bien, como determinas cual es la primera fecha y la segunda? Es por medio del modal que compartiste en la imagen que planeas hacer el update?

CON EL UPDATE quiero actualizar las fechas nadamas

La nueva edición de la pregunta no aclara gran cosa. ¿Podrías verbalizar el criterio a seguir para hacer la actualización? Eso es fundamental para pensar en una solución del problema. Si es un criterio temporal puedes programar un evento y si es un criterio de orden, puedes filtrar por la fecha más próxima, o puedes lanzar una consulta que busque por fechas las vacaciones que se deben actualizar, siempre según el criterio que se debe seguir para hacer las actualizaciones. A veces el problema es no saber explicar el problema, explicándolo, encuentras la solución.

No uses palabras técnicas. Por ejemplo di: Quiero actualizar las fechas de vacaciones de Juan (con ID_Personal 1) y que se haga así y así... Pero que no interfiera con las de Maria (con ID_Personal 2) porque perteneces al mismo departamento (id_dept) y así... Porque no se te entiende, ayyy we mi mente
